# First small foodstore-project with ajax - does not execute

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have just started to learn Ajax and have watched a tutorial on how to write a small input that checks whether a foodstore has something in stock or whether it hasn't.

I have double-checked the code several times but it still does not execute anything. I would be glad if anyone could help me here.

The code is basically three files:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="foodstore.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="process()">

<h3>The Food Store</h3>

<p>Enter the food you would like to have:</p>
<input type="text" id="userInput">
<div id="underInput"/>

</body>

</html>
```

**foodstore.php**

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
$food = $_GET['food'];
$foodArray = array('tuna', 'bacon', 'beef', 'ham');
if(in_array($food,$foodArray)) {
    echo 'We do have '.$food'!';
echo '</response>';
}
}


?>
```

**and finally the foodstore.js**

```
    var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

    function createXmlHttpRequestObject() {
        var xmlHttp;

        if(window.ActiveXObject) {
            try{
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e){
                xmlHttp = false;
            }
        }else{
             try{
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch(e){
                xmlHttp = false;
            }
        }

        if(!xmlHttp)
            alert("Cant create that object!");

        else {
            return xmlHttp;
        }
    }

    // This is now the communication part!

    function process() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            food =          encodeURIComponent(document.getElmentById("userInput").value);
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food=" + food, true);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }else{
            setTimeout('process()',1000);
        }
    }

    function handleServerResponse() {

        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            if(xmlHttp.status==200){
                xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
                xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
                message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
                document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = '<span styel="color:blue">' + message + '</span>';
                setTimeout('process()',1000);
            }else{
                alter('Something went wrong!');
            }
        }

    }
```

I would really appreciate some help. I also read in the youtube-comments that jQuery would rather be easier to use as far as the js part goes. Is that true?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know where to start. Almost everything, possibly just everything, is wrong here. Find a different tutorial and start again.

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually the tutorial seemed to be quite good. Was made by thenewboston.com and was rated quite positive. I thought I would have maybe a minor mistake in here..?

Answer (score 0):

In the foodstore.js you have a litlle problem you have writed document.getElmentById("userInput").value and it must be
document.getElementById("userInput").value